# PHPExcel - memory leak when I go through all rows

Tags: php, memory, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel library for reading xls and xlsx files. Below is a sample function for demonstrating problem that I have:

```
public function memoryAction()
{
    $filename = "example.xlsx";

    echo "<br>Script started<br>";
    echo memory_get_usage(true);

    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filename);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(array('OTMS','Printing'));

    $excelReader = $objReader->load($filename);

    echo "<br>Reader Initiliazed<br>";
    echo memory_get_usage(true);

    foreach ($excelReader->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        if ($row->getRowIndex() == 1) {
            continue;
        }

        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

        $excelRow = array();

        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            $columnIndex = $cell->getColumn();
            $cellValue = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            $excelRow[$columnIndex] = $cellValue;

        }

        if (empty($excelRow)) {
            continue;
        }

        echo "<br>Row ".$row->getRowIndex()."<br>";
        echo memory_get_usage(true);



    }

    echo "<br>Went through each row<br>";
    echo memory_get_usage(true);

    die();


}
```

So, basically I go through each row in Excel table and output memory usage. The thing is that memory usage increases after each 20-30 rows.

Here are values that I get:

Script started    1835008 -1,75 Mb

Reader Initiliazed   19660800 - 18,75 Mb

Went through each row  47972352 - 45,75 Mb

I read several posts on Internet about PHPExcel memory problem. Yes, it consumes a lot of memory. You can see, that I use setReadDataOnly() function and that I uploaded only specific worksheets. But I still don't understand why just looping through rows consumes memory.

Is there any way to unset row/cell objects in the loop and free up memory? Appreciate any help.

---

UPD

I have run Mark's code and here is a result for my file:

```
Base Memory: 1835008
Reader Initialised/File Loaded
19660800
Row 256 memory usage: 24903680
Row 512 memory usage: 33030144
Row 768 memory usage: 38797312
Went through each row
Final memory usage: 48234496
```

I'm using PHPExcel version 1.7.8. and PHP 5.5.11. Probably it's worth to update PHPExcel library.

---

UPD 2

I have installed version 1.8.0 of PHPExcel library. Here are results of the Mark's code:

```
Base Memory: 1835008
Reader Initialised/File Loaded
15990784
Row 256 memory usage: 20185088
Row 512 memory usage: 27262976
Row 768 memory usage: 31719424
Went through each row
Final memory usage: 40108032
```

Any ideas why it happens? I'm using Zend Framework and called this code in action controller. Test file contains 4 tabs, file size - 619 KB. Code works with first tab only which contains 1000 rows.

Comment: Is this the actual code you're using to test the memory usage? Because you should be displaying the memory after iterating through the columns in each row, and that isn't shown in the question. I see you're building an array of cells from each row (`$excelRow[$columnIndex] = $cellValue;`: are you actually building an array of rows as well? It does raise the question of why you feel the need to build an array in the first place, and secondly why you don't use PHPExcel's built-in methods to do this for you.

Comment: Just looping through rows doesn't consume extra memory in PHPExcel

Comment: @MarkBaker yes, it's an actual code that I use for testing. I didn't add information about memory usage after each iteration because there are many lines in output. I'm building array of cells because eventually I will pass each row data to another function for processing.

Comment: Then can you see the memory usage increasing with each row? I'd like to know where that memory is going as well. I know that looping through rows doesn't consume extra memory in PHPExcel, so I can't explain it from your code.... the only additional memory is the cellIterator, and that's a minimal amount of memory that's re-used in each iteration rather than cumulative

Comment: It also still doesn't explain why you don't simply use PHPExcel's built-in toArray() or rangeToArray() methods

Comment: @MarkBaker ok, I will try built-in function toArray(). I think I wasn't very accurate in describing my issue. Looping through rows doesn't consume additional memory indeed. But when I add initializing of cellIterator in the loop - memory usage increases. And that's what I don't understand. Why it happens?

Comment: I can't understand how it could happen, but I'll run some tests myself tomorrow..... if the iterators really are using so much memory (more than doubling memory usage) then you've discovered a serious flaw somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a single worksheet file with 8192 rows and 32 columns just as a test. The script that I'm running to read this is based on the script you've posted above:

```
echo "Base Memory: ", memory_get_usage(true), PHP_EOL;

$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify('volumeTest.xlsx');
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$excelReader = $objReader->load('volumeTest.xlsx');

echo "Reader Initialised/File Loaded", PHP_EOL;
echo memory_get_usage(true), PHP_EOL;

foreach ($excelReader->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        $columnIndex = $cell->getColumn();
        $cellValue = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
    }
    if (($row->getRowIndex() % 256) == 0) {
        echo "Row ".$row->getRowIndex(), ' memory usage: ', memory_get_usage(true), PHP_EOL;
    }
}

echo "Went through each row", PHP_EOL;
echo "Final memory usage: ", memory_get_usage(true), PHP_EOL;
```

so I'm iterating through the rows and columns in exactly the same way you are, and the only real differences are that I'm only displaying the memory usage every 256 rows of iteration rather than every row, and that I'm not building an array of cell values.

The output that this generates is:

`Base Memory: 524288
Reader Initialised/File Loaded
105119744
Row 256 memory usage: 105119744
Row 512 memory usage: 105119744
Row 768 memory usage: 105119744
Row 1024 memory usage: 105119744
Row 1280 memory usage: 105119744
Row 1536 memory usage: 105119744
Row 1792 memory usage: 105119744
Row 2048 memory usage: 105119744
Row 2304 memory usage: 105119744
Row 2560 memory usage: 105119744
Row 2816 memory usage: 105119744
Row 3072 memory usage: 105119744
Row 3328 memory usage: 105119744
Row 3584 memory usage: 105119744
Row 3840 memory usage: 105119744
Row 4096 memory usage: 105119744
Row 4352 memory usage: 105119744
Row 4608 memory usage: 105119744
Row 4864 memory usage: 105119744
Row 5120 memory usage: 105119744
Row 5376 memory usage: 105119744
Row 5632 memory usage: 105119744
Row 5888 memory usage: 105119744
Row 6144 memory usage: 105119744
Row 6400 memory usage: 105119744
Row 6656 memory usage: 105119744
Row 6912 memory usage: 105119744
Row 7168 memory usage: 105119744
Row 7424 memory usage: 105119744
Row 7680 memory usage: 105119744
Row 7936 memory usage: 105119744
Row 8192 memory usage: 105119744
Went through each row
Final memory usage: 105119744`

Showing no memory usage changes at any point during the row iterations

I've run these tests now using the PHPExcel versions 1.7.9, 1.8.0 and the latest development branch against PHP versions 5.2.17, 5.3.27, 5.4.7, 5.4.21, 5.5.5 and 5.6.0 and have seen no variation of memory usage within the iterators with any combination of PHPExcel/PHP.

Comment: Thank you for help, Mark. I have updated post with result of this test. Unfortunately in my case memory is increasing. I'm using PHPExcel 1.7.8 - could it be a problem?

Comment: 1.7.8 shouldn't be any different using the iterators compared with the later releases, the iterator code was unchanged between 1.7.8 and 1.8.0: and though develop has some differences (a column iterator, specifying start/end ranges, etc), none of them show any memory leak