# PHPExcel 1.8.0 memory exhausted on load, chunk read, and iterator

Tags: php, excel, memory

I have already set my php configuration setttings to upload 12800M files, inifinite size files, and upload time infinity for testing, but I have been stuck on this common PHPExcel fatal memory exhausted error. I receive the common error message below:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in .../Worksheet.php on line 1220.

When I use chunk read filters or iterators, as the .xlsx file is read further into the rows, the memory usage increases instead of staying the same as some have reported from what I read from PHPExcel developers I believe.

I am on PHPExcel 1.8.0. I might try an older version, since I have read that reading large files have been performing better. I started with a regular load the file and read it into an array, use chunk read filtering as in the example, and iterator at this URL: [PHPExcel - memory leak when I go through all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858484/phpexcel-memory-leak-when-i-go-through-all-rows). I would think that it wouldn't matter if it was version 1.8.0 or older.

```
<?php

/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

/** Include PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


if (!file_exists("Test.xlsx")) {
    exit("Please check if Test.xlsx exists first.\n");
}

echo date('H:i:s') , " Load workbook from Excel5 file" , EOL;
$callStartTime = microtime(true);

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("Order_Short.xls");

$callEndTime = microtime(true);
$callTime = $callEndTime - $callStartTime;

echo 'Call time to load Workbook was ' , sprintf('%.4f',$callTime) , " seconds" , EOL;
// Echo memory usage
echo date('H:i:s') , ' Current memory usage: ' , (memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;


//http://runnable.com/Uot2A2l8VxsUAAAR/read-a-simple-2007-xlsx-excel-file-for-php

//  Read your Excel workbook
$inputFileName="Drybar Client Data for Tableau Test.xlsx";
$table = "mt_company2_project2_table144_raw";

try {
    echo date('H:i:s') , " Load workbook from Excel5 file" , EOL;
    $callStartTime = microtime(true);

    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

    $callEndTime = microtime(true);
    $callTime = $callEndTime - $callStartTime;

    echo 'Call time to load Workbook was ' , sprintf('%.4f',$callTime) , " seconds\r\n" , EOL;
    // Echo memory usage
    echo date('H:i:s') , ' Current memory usage: ' , (memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME)
        . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
}

// Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);

// http://asantillan.com/php-excel-import-to-mysql-using-phpexcel/
$worksheetTitle = $sheet->getTitle();

$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

// Calculationg Columns
$nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;

echo "File ".$worksheetTitle." has ";
echo $nrColumns . ' columns';
echo ' x ' . $highestRow . ' rows.<br />';

//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                    NULL, FALSE, FALSE);

    var_dump($rowData);

    foreach ($rowData[0] as $k => $v) {
        echo "Row: " . $row . "- Col: " . ($k + 1) . " = " . $v . "<br />";
    }

}
```

I am including chunk read filter modified from PHPExcel Reader Example #12 that still gives me the same fatal memory exhausted since it's memory usage is increasing still as it read further down the rows?

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

/**  Set Include path to point at the PHPExcel Classes folder  **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../../Classes/');

/**  Include PHPExcel_IOFactory  **/
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileName = 'Test.xlsx';


/**  Define a Read Filter class implementing PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter  */
class chunkReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
{
    private $_startRow = 0;

    private $_endRow = 0;

    /**  Set the list of rows that we want to read  */
    public function setRows($startRow, $chunkSize) {
        $this->_startRow    = $startRow;
        $this->_endRow      = $startRow + $chunkSize;
    }

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
        //  Only read the heading row, and the rows that are configured in $this->_startRow and $this->_endRow
        if (($row == 1) || ($row >= $this->_startRow && $row < $this->_endRow)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);

$callStartTime = microtime(true);

echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory with a defined reader type of ',$inputFileType,'<br />';

// Call time

$callEndTime = microtime(true);
$callTime = $callEndTime - $callStartTime;
echo 'Call time to read Workbook was ' , sprintf('%.4f',$callTime) , " seconds" , EOL;

// Echo memory usage
echo date('H:i:s') , ' Current memory usage: ' , (memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;

/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

echo '<hr />';


/**  Define how many rows we want to read for each "chunk"  **/
$chunkSize = 100;
/**  Create a new Instance of our Read Filter  **/
$chunkFilter = new chunkReadFilter();

/**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter that we've Instantiated  **/
$objReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);
/**  Loop to read our worksheet in "chunk size" blocks  **/
for ($startRow = 2; $startRow <= 26000; $startRow += $chunkSize) {
    echo 'Loading WorkSheet using configurable filter for headings row 1 and for rows ',$startRow,' to ',($startRow+$chunkSize-1),'<br />';
    /**  Tell the Read Filter, the limits on which rows we want to read this iteration  **/
    $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow,$chunkSize);
    /**  Load only the rows that match our filter from $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

    //  Do some processing here

    $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

    echo '<br /><br />';

    // Call time

    $callEndTime = microtime(true);
    $callTime = $callEndTime - $callStartTime;
    echo 'Call time to read Workbook was ' , sprintf('%.4f',$callTime) , " seconds" , EOL;

    // Echo memory usage
    echo date('H:i:s') , ' Current memory usage: ' , (memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;

    // Echo memory peak usage
    echo date('H:i:s') , " Peak memory usage: " , (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;
    echo '<hr />';
}

?>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: No use of chunking in the code you've posted, so I can't comment on that; but have you looked at cell caching?

Comment: And where is the code failing? Has it loaded the file (a chunk or otherwise)? Or is it during the load?

Comment: Sorry, I have included the chunking in the second code snippet. I have looked at cell caching. I have noticed any improvements with this fatal memory exhausted error. The first code fails on files larger than 2MB on load.

Comment: You should be disconnecting the worksheets and unsetting the current PHPExcel object after processing it in the loop before the next chunk iteration, as described in the documentation..... note that chunking doesn't eliminate all memory usage, but it does reduce it

Comment: I have already attempted implementing $objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets(); unset($objPHPExcel, $sheetData); after my for-loop iteration, but I still get the exact same fatal memory exhausted error...

Comment: Have you tried cell caching?

Comment: Where does the code fall over? Is it in the load? Or is it in the loop?

Comment: Yes, I have tried cell caching too. I still get the same fatal memory exhausted error. The chunk read filter code falls over in the loop.

Comment: Then perhaps you might consider using smaller chunks; but I have never managed to replicate a chunk loop where memory increased

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have a major problem here:

```
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

which will try to build an array for the entire size of the worksheet regardless of whether you chunk loaded or not.... toArray() uses the expected size of the spreadsheet based on the file that you're loading, not the filtered set of cells that you're loading

Try getting only the range of cells that you've loaded through the chunk using rangeToArray() instead

```
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->rangeToArray(
        'A'.$startRow.':'.$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn().($startRow+$chunkSize-1),
        null,
        true,
        true,
        true
    );
```

Even then, building PHP arrays in memory uses a lot of memory; your code will be a lot less memory-hungry if it can process that worksheet data one row at a time rather than populating a large array

Comment: I am still getting the fatal memory exhausted error using the rangToArray instead of toArray. It seems that rangeToArray runs into the same issue as toArray.

Comment: What range are you requesting? __building PHP arrays in memory uses a lot of memory__ It is far, far better to  process that worksheet data one row at a time rather than to build a large array in memory

Comment: Strange, I ran it on a LAMP stack versus the WAMP stack I was using, and  no problem on the LAMP stack. I might be running into a Windows OS memory management issue.